# Can a @Persistent field of an App Engine Data Store be changed to be non-@Persistent?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a persistent class in an Java App Engine app such as this:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class SomeClass {

    //  <snip> some fields

    @Persistent(serialized="true")
    private Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Which has worked up to now, but the data in the map is getting too big and going over the App Engine 1MB limit.

The source data is in a blob, so instead of persisting the calculated map data, I will recalculate from source blob when the dataMap needs to be accessed - it'll be slower, but can accommodate much larger entities.

However, to do that I wish to keep the field, but tell App Engine it's no longer persistent (i.e do not try to populate the data from datastore) so that I can populate it myself based on the blob data.

If I remove the `@Persistent` - when loading a previously saved entity I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob cannot be cast to java.util.Map
in .jdoReplaceField()
```

Looks like the data in data store is trying to be set to the class via the getter (without the benefit of the serialised annotation). I thought that if the field was not marked Persistent, it would not have data from the datastore applied to it.

Is this expected behaviour or a bug? How should this be done, do I need to delete the map data from every entity in the datastore first? Do I need to change the field name to e.g newDataMap?

Edit: I tested field names (same setter/getter names) and that fixes the error, so when App Engine is applying the datastore data, it seems the field name matching a field in the datastore data is what matters, not the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to specifically annotate the fields as `@NotPersistent` I had missed it in [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses#Class_and_Field_Annotations), but the default is to try and persist.